# Not able to style nested animations with keyframes with styled-components

Tags: css, reactjs, frontend, styled-components

I am creating the animation for an Image with a customized animation in styled-component with conditional styling. But it gives me the error saying that

> "Uncaught Error: It seems you are interpolating a keyframe declaration
>   (bZfjDs) into an untagged string. This was supported in
>   styled-components v3, but is not longer supported in v4 as keyframes
>   are now injected on-demand. Please wrap your string in the css``
>   helper (see https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#css), which
>   ensures the styles are injected correctly."

I did it with the v4 syntax but it still does not work. Is there a way to do it?

I've tried follow the syntax but it still won't work.

First I did:

```
animation: ${props => (props.animating === 'true' ? `${fadeInSlide} 1s ease-in-out infinite forwards` : '')} ;
```

where fadeInSlide is my own keyframes, then I tried doing:

```
const fadeInAnimation = css`
    animation: ${fadeInSlide} 1s ease-in-out infinite forwards;
  `
const BlockImage = styled(Image)`
  animation: ${props => (props.animated === 'true' ? `${fadeInAnimation}` : '')} ;
`
```

but this also gives me the error.

Answer (score 22):

What worked for me was adding the `css` property. Perhaps this could help:

```js
animation: ${props => (props.animating === 'true' ? css`${fadeInSlide} 1s ease-in-out infinite forwards` : '')} ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding onto Gav's answer - your ternary operator may be incorrect. In JavaScript true is NOT equal to 'true'. You also may need to add a semicolon.

Try

```
animation: ${props => (props.animating === true ? css`${fadeInSlide} 1s ease-in-out infinite forwards;` : '')} ;
```

Or

```
animation: ${props => (props.animating ? css`${fadeInSlide} 1s ease-in-out infinite forwards;` : '')} ;
```